# Statistics (Faster Win = Higher Certainty of Superiority?)

Tags: statistics

I have a question about statistics and I'm not quite sure how to explain it concisely so please bear with me.

I am ranking characters in a video game called Mugen (2D fighting game) by order of strength. I am doing AI vs AI matches and ranking them in order of strength. A would go up against B, both trying to deplete each other's HP but never doing so because I've set the HP to near infinite.

If I leave the test running and I come back later to find that A has a lot more HP remaining than B, then it is obvious that A > B. I've set the threshold to 30,000 HP. If A has 30k HP more than B, then I adjudicate A as the winner.

The "sample size" would just be how long I leave the test running. The longer the test, the more accurate the answer. I see little point in having more than one test for each pairing when I can simply let one test go on forever.

---

Isn't this approach somewhat flawed? If A quickly gets 30k more HP than B, doesn't that demonstrate A is much stronger than B, so it's more certain A > B? Vice versa: If A takes forever to reach 30k over B, isn't it less certain A > B?

If that is true, shouldn't I require more than a 30k lead if A is taking a long time to reach the 30k threshold?

I'm trying to draw a parallel to chess. Maybe my question is like asking: What if engine A takes a long time to score a lead in points over engine B? Shouldn't I therefore increase my sample size in response to this? I've heard from some people that it depends on how similar in strength the two engines are. I don't know if that makes sense, and I don't think that's applicable and helps in any way with my Mugen testing.

---

With the little info I've listed here (I could list more, but you'd be sitting here forever), do you figure that elo would be a good system to rank these guys?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

that sounds like a reasonable way to determine relative strength strictly within the context of ai vs ai, and i dont think its flawed given the repetitiveness of ai. but the results will probably not be very insightful if youre trying to factor them for player v player matchups. ai isnt necessarily designed to deal damage as quickly as possible, so human players would probably better leverage the strengths of the characters and give you very different results.

Comment: Thank you, that does help! I am not intending to rank characters by order of how good they are when a human uses it (that would also be nearly impossible to test). I am just looking for strength when AI goes up against AI.